# How is $\tan^{-1}(a/b) = \tan^{-1}(a) - \tan^{-1}(b)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having a problem proving:

$\tan^{-1}(a/b) = \tan^{-1}(a) - \tan^{-1}(b)$

Thanks!

Comment: You might be thinking about $\ln(a/b) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also have a problem proving this: setting $b=1$, we get $\arctan a$ on the left and $\arctan a-\frac{\pi}{4}$ on the right.

Answer (score 4):

Then $\tan$ on both sides of the equation and use $\tan(x-y) = \frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}$ to obtain

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a-b}{1+ab}$$

Thus the equation can only be satisfied if $a$ and $b$ satisfy the equation above.